# Making multiple request with progress bar in a table using asihttp request

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, asihttprequest

I am using asihhtp request to making multiple request for image uploading in ios to submit image to the server.But my application always crashing due to progress bar. this is my code

```
                ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
                [request appendPostData:postData];
                [request setTag:[[dic objectForKey:@"unique"] integerValue]];
                [request setDelegate:self];
                [request setUploadProgressDelegate:cell.mProgressBar];
                [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFail:)];
                [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
                [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
                [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/plain"];
                [request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
                //[myQueue addOperation:request];
                [appDelegate window].userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                [request startAsynchronous];
```

where i have custom cell in which i have progress bar and a label so once process is completed i am hiding bar and showing completed lable.

Problem when user scroll table app crash use to progress bar

crash output

```
> -[UIProgressView respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x10d210c0
```

Custom cell code

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface CustomProgressBar : UITableViewCell
    {

    }

    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel         *mlblCompllrtrlbl;
    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView  *mProgressBar;
    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView     *mCellImafge;

    @end
```

Custom cell code

```
    #import "CustomProgressBar.h"

    @implementation CustomProgressBar
    @synthesize mlblCompllrtrlbl;
    @synthesize mProgressBar;
    @synthesize mCellImafge;

    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)reuseIdentifier
    {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
    }

    - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
   {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
   }

   - (void)dealloc 
   {
    [mCellImafge release];
    [mlblCompllrtrlbl release];
    [mProgressBar release];
    [super dealloc];
   }

   @end
```

Comment: Can you pls post your custom cell code header/implementation file ?

Comment: Did you get any solution for your problem?I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might have released progressview somewhere, so first remove the statement

[UIProgressView release];

Comment: no i am not removing. my guess is when i am scrolling then something wrong happen there

Answer (score 0):

table cells are auto release so whenever you scroll table then progressview will be release and may be you are trying to access that progessView's method

Answer (score 0):

Your tableviewcell will be either be released or reused (depending on how you setup reuse identifiers) when it goes off screen.

You need to keep track of your requests somehow, in a way that is independent of the table view cell. You probably need a separate object that represents each request stored in an NSArray that belongs to the view controller, or belongs to some other object that has the same lifetime as your want the requests to have.